# How to generate random strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, random

How do you create a random string in Python?

I need it to be number then character, repeating until the iteration is done.

This is what I created:

```
def random_id(length):
    number = '0123456789'
    alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    id = ''
    for i in range(0,length,2):
        id += random.choice(number)
        id += random.choice(alpha)
    return id
```

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Generating strings from (for example) lowercase characters:

```
import random, string

def randomword(length):
   letters = string.ascii_lowercase
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
```

Results:

```
>>> randomword(10)
'vxnxikmhdc'
>>> randomword(10)
'ytqhdohksy'
```

Comment: Best answer so far. I'd use `randomword(length, source_alpha=string.lowercase)` and `xrange(length)`, though.

Comment: Note that although this is a very good answer, the OP has modified the question to invalidate it. And to provide his/her own answer.

Comment: For Python 3 compatibility, use `string.ascii_lowercase`

Comment: if you call randomword() more often, this is going to waste lots of cpu.

Comment: From Python 3.6, `random.choices` would be faster.

Comment: Just to nitpick: [PEP 8 specify that "imports should usually be on separate lines"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: `random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=length)`

Answer (score 84):

Since this question is fairly, uh, random, this may work for you:

```py
import uuid
print(uuid.uuid4())
```

```
58fe9784-f60a-42bc-aa94-eb8f1a7e5c17
```

Comment: In many cases, random isn't really required. Rather, all you really need is unique.

Comment: you could use `str(uuid.uuid4())` if you want to use it as a string.

Comment: `str(uuid.uuid4()).split("-")[0]`
Output:
`'4bcb6450'`

Comment: Good point, Vlad. 
For something longer, ''.join(str(uuid.uuid4()).split('-')) also works. Output: '00db8a458c71415c9a263ff08667dd93'

Comment: Or simpler `uuid.uuid4().hex` -> `'2c97755f633c4bdba624630954f94962'`

Answer (score 46):

```py
import random
import string

s = string.lowercase+string.digits
print(''.join(random.sample(s, 10)))
# prints 'jw72qidagk'
```

Comment: Neat! I'm actually using this for a random password generator now! Thanks!

Comment: random.sample will sample unique characters from s, ie characters in the password will never repeat. This is considerably less secure than the using random.choice as in the accepted answer.

Comment: @NickZalutskiy: `random.choice` is not secure either. Use `random.SystemRandom().choice()` or [use `os.urandom()` directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16310739/4279).

Comment: WARNING! take note of two comments above. random.sample returns unique samples. characters are not repeated. so returned string is less random. For larger strings error: 'ValueError: sample larger than population'.

Comment: Also a consequence of the above comments - the sample cannot be larger than the selected chars ("population"), so even if you don't need this for any security-related task, you cannot make long strings with `random.sample`. Fortunately, using a generator with `rand.choice` is just as simple.

Comment: simple but misleading solution. As stated above, sample will not do wat people expect in most cases. Better to use `random.choices` for that matter.

Comment: In Python 3, `lowercase` should be replaced with `ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 19):

Answer to the original question:

```
os.urandom(n)
```

Quote from: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

> Return a string of n random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.
>
> This function returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness
>   source. The returned data should be unpredictable enough for
>   cryptographic applications, though its exact quality depends on the OS
>   implementation. On a UNIX-like system this will query /dev/urandom,
>   and on Windows it will use CryptGenRandom. If a randomness source is
>   not found, NotImplementedError will be raised.
>
> For an easy-to-use interface to the random number generator provided
>   by your platform, please see random.SystemRandom.

Answer (score 6):

You can build random ascii characters like:

```
import random
print chr(random.randint(0,128))
```

And then build up a longer string like:

```
len = 50
print ''.join( [chr(random.randint(0,128)) for i in xrange(0,len)] )
```

Comment: Why use string formatting? `''.join(map(chr, random.randint(0,256) for _ in xrange(len)))`

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, I've wanted random strings that are semi-pronounceable, semi-memorable.

```
import random

def randomWord(length=5):
    consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    vowels = "aeiou"

    return "".join(random.choice((consonants, vowels)[i%2]) for i in range(length))
```

Then,

```
>>> randomWord()
nibit
>>> randomWord()
piber
>>> randomWord(10)
rubirikiro
```

To avoid 4-letter words, don't set `length` to 4.

Jim

Answer (score 6):

In `python3.6+` you can use the [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets):

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong
> random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account
> authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default
> pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed
> for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

In testing generation of `768bit` security tokens I found:

- `random.choices()` - `0.000246` secs
- `secrets.choice()` - `0.003529` secs

The `secrets` modules is slower but outside of testing it is what you should be using for cryptographic purposes:

```
import string, secrets

def random_string(size):        
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits            
        return ''.join(secrets.choice(letters) for i in range(size))

print(random_string(768))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer :). I'd like to add that `secrets.token_hex(n)` also returns a random string, not with uppercase characters, but still, a random string of characters and numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't really said much about what sort of random string you need. But in any case, you should look into the `random` module.

A very simple solution is pasted below.

```
import random

def randstring(length=10):
    valid_letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    return ''.join((random.choice(valid_letters) for i in xrange(length)))

print randstring()
print randstring(20)
```

Comment: fyi you can omit the outermost set of parens in your return statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
random_name = lambda length: ''.join(random.sample(string.letters, length))
```

length must be <= len(string.letters) = 53.
result example

```
   >>> [random_name(x) for x in range(1,20)]
['V', 'Rq', 'YtL', 'AmUF', 'loFdS', 'eNpRFy', 'iWFGtDz', 'ZTNgCvLA', 'fjUDXJvMP', 'EBrPcYKUvZ', 'GmxPKCnbfih', 'nSiNmCRktdWZ', 'VWKSsGwlBeXUr', 'i
stIFGTUlZqnav', 'bqfwgBhyTJMUEzF', 'VLXlPiQnhptZyoHq', 'BXWATvwLCUcVesFfk', 'jLngHmTBtoOSsQlezV', 'JOUhklIwDBMFzrTCPub']
>>>
```

Enjoy. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Install this package:

```
pip3 install py_essentials
```

And use this code:

```
from py_essentials import simpleRandom as sr
print(sr.randomString(4))
```

[More informations about the method other parameters are available here.](https://github.com/phyyyl/py_essentials/wiki/simpleRandom)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random 
import string

def get_random_string(size):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits
    ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

print(get_random_string(20)
```

***output : FfxjmkyyLG5HvLeRudDS***

Answer (score 0):

This function generates random string consisting of upper,lowercase letters, digits, pass the length seperator, no_of_blocks to specify your string format

eg: len_sep = 4, no_of_blocks = 4 will generate the following pattern,

> F4nQ-Vh5z-JKEC-WhuS

Where, length seperator will add "-" after 4 characters

> **XXXX-**

no of blocks will generate the following patten of characters as string

> **XXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXX**

if a single random string is needed, just keep the no_of_blocks variable to be equal to 1 and len_sep to specify the length of the random string.

eg: len_sep = 10, no_of_blocks = 1, will generate the following pattern ie. random string of **length 10**,

> **F01xgCdoDU**

```
import random as r

def generate_random_string(len_sep, no_of_blocks):
    random_string = ''
    random_str_seq = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for i in range(0,len_sep*no_of_blocks):
        if i % len_sep == 0 and i != 0:
            random_string += '-'
        random_string += str(random_str_seq[r.randint(0, len(random_str_seq) - 1)])
    return random_string
```

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation:

```
def generate_random_letters(length: int, uppercase: bool = True, lowercase: bool = True, numbers: bool = True):
choices = ''
if uppercase:
    choices += string.ascii_uppercase

if lowercase:
    choices += string.ascii_lowercase

if numbers:
    choices += string.digits

return ''.join(random.choice(choices) for _ in range(length))
```