# How to generate a random string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a code where is generates a random string, but I have only just started coding so I don't want anything to the code to be too complicated.

```
import random, string
randomthing = random.choice(string)
print(randomthing(10))
```

But it keeps saying the length (len) is not defined. What should I do?

Comment: `string` is a module and module don't have `len` function. Perhaps you want `string.ascii_lowercase`. Also note that `randomthing(10)` will give an `IndexError`

Comment: I think what you should do is read a tutorial to learn the differences between a variable, a module and a function.

Comment: Can you explain what this will be used for? What characters do you want to permit in your random string? Just letters? Numbers? Punctuation? Printable ASCII? Arbitrary ASCII? Arbitrary Unicode?

Comment: related: [Fastest method to generate big random string with lower Latin letters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16308989/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string` module does not literary have `len` you might want to try this:

Python2:

```
rand_str = lambda n: ''.join([random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(n)])

# Now to generate a random string of length 10
s = rand_str(10)
```

Python3:

```
rand_str = lambda n: ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(n)])

# Now to generate a random string of length 10
s = rand_str(10)
```

`random.choice` returns a single character and 10 such characters are joined using the `join` function.

**EDIT**

`lambda n : ...` creates a lambda function which takes `n` as the argument.

`''.join(sequence)` joins a sequence into a string with empty string (`''` ) between them i.e. it simply joins characters into words.
`'.'.join(['a','b','c'])` will for example, return `a.b.c`.

Comment: what does the lamba, and join bit do?

Comment: @Izzy Edited the answer with an explanation.

Comment: unrelated: a fast way to generate a random non-deterministic bytestring is `os.urandom(n)`. If you need to limit the allowed bytes; a care should be taken [to avoid the skew, see `write_random_ascii_lowercase_letters()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16310739/4279)

Answer (score 16):

In case, you want to generate unique strings:

```
import uuid
print uuid.uuid4() # e3c8a1c3-9965-4356-9072-1002632a96e1
print uuid.uuid4().hex # e3c8a1c39965435690721002632a96e1
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been already answered in [Random strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030053/random-strings-in-python) 
Generating strings from (for example) lowercase characters:

```
import random, string

def randomword(length):
   return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for i in range(length))
```

Results:

```
>>> randomword(10)
'vxnxikmhdc'
>>> randomword(10)
'ytqhdohksy'
```

Comment: yes, but what does each bit do, for example I am confused on why you add the join and for i bit

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I think about random strings it reminds me about [Lorem Ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum). It exists the [loremipsum python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/loremipsum/) which you can use like this:

```
from loremipsum import get_sentences
sentences_list = get_sentences(5)
```

If you don't mind about the exact number of char in the string, it may be a nice solution to generate random strings that look like sentences.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1:

Generate a random number between 97 and 122 (including both) using `random.randint(97,122)`

STEP 2:

Convert the random number to a letter using `str(unichr(<random number>))`

STEP 3:

Append the string to the final string

something like:

```
randomString=""
for i in range(10):
    randomString += (str(unichr(random.randint(97,122)))) #intended to put tab space.
print randomString                                        #I'm new to Stackoverflow
```

Comment: Just for Python 3.* users: substitute 'unichr' with 'chr'