# Does Python have a library that produces data as fast os.urandom but is reproducible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-data

Is there a Python library that can produce random data as fast as os.urandom, but the data can be reproduced if given a seed?

Comment: How did your search on "Python random seed" not turn up the hits?

Comment: You do know the difference between what `os.urandom` does and pseudo-random generators do, right?

Comment: The speeds given by `pv < /dev/urandom > /dev/null` vary significantly between systems. Mine cluster around ~13MiB/s, with one producing ~180MiB/s. These aren't particularly fast rates. What are you going to be using this random data for?

Comment: I know that os.urandom is totally random, but I could not find a suitable pseudo-random generator that did a similar thing. I'm using the data to test write functionality to a bunch of luns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.seed` to produce a reproducible sequence. The only problem is getting Python to produce random bytes quickly. You can use [a trick observed by @jfs with `random.getrandbits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310739/464744) to reduce the amount of processing Python has to do:

```
import random

def almost_urandom(n):
    return random.getrandbits(8 * n).to_bytes(n, 'big')
```

`random.seed` lets you deterministically generate the bytes:

```
In [26]: random.seed(0)

In [27]: almost_urandom(10)
Out[27]: b'\xc2\tb\x9fo\xbe\xd8,\x07\xcd'

In [28]: almost_urandom(10)
Out[28]: b'\n]k\xaa\x94U\xe3\xe7\x06\x82'

In [29]: random.seed(0)

In [30]: almost_urandom(10)
Out[30]: b'\xc2\tb\x9fo\xbe\xd8,\x07\xcd'

In [31]: almost_urandom(10)
Out[31]: b'\n]k\xaa\x94U\xe3\xe7\x06\x82'
```

It runs an order of magnitude faster than `os.urandom()` for me, even for `n` in the millions.