# Random data for test automation in python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using unittest and selenium to automate my browser testing.

How would I go about making a test which I can run multiple times, where a user creates a ticket. The ticket has to has a title name, each time I run the test I want the title name to be random.

I would like the format: "Test ticket, 1 | Test ticket, 2..."

Comment: What are you having problems with? `Ticket 1`, `Ticket 2`, ... are trivial to create.

Comment: The example you showed doesn't seem very random. Also, is that format describing a single ticket, a list of tickets separated by commas, a list of tickets separated by pipes, or… what? Please describe the intended output less vaguely.

Comment: a single ticket, each time i run the test, it should create 1 ticket. There are other steps included but I just want to cover the name part. I am sure its really simple, but I am noob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [faker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Faker/0.0.4) module offers some functionality to populate several different types of data:

```
import faker
f = faker.Faker()

In [11]: f.
f.city            f.full_address    f.phonenumber     f.zip_code
f.company         f.last_name       f.state
f.email           f.lorem           f.street_address
f.first_name      f.name            f.username

In [11]: f.city()
Out[11]: u'Treyview'
```

.

If you are going to *test* randomly, I recommend randomly generating a [seed](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) (and logging it), that way you can recreate any failing tests. *What you don't want is tests which fail but it's unclear why (i.e. if testing again, with different random values, passes).*

Comment: thanks for the advice, I am not sure what you mean randomly generating a seed, could you provide some code for me to look at :). I am guessing that when I get to the ticket form, and send_keys, this is where I will need to have a generator?

Comment: @JacobHong I wonder if what you *really* want is something like [Faker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Faker/0.0.4)...

Comment: this is more than I wanted, Im studying the documents now thanks :)

Comment: @JacobHong I think I'm just oing to change my answer to that... annoyingly it doesn't seem to offer a seed function... yet.

Comment: I put together a python module which has better locale support (using ruby's data), I haven't put it in the cheese shop though: https://github.com/hayd/pyfaker

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the string `Test ticket,1 ...` it is:

```
from random import randint
randomString = "Test ticket, " + randint(min,max)
```

If you want to generate random strings you could use

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(max))
```

You also might want to think about preventing strings to be equal.
In that case you could create a `range(min,max)` and use `random.shuffle()`

Comment: thanks this is pretty much what I was looking for, I want to add on one more question. How can I make the test case, run multiple times? just add a loop or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following functions in your test:

```
import random, string

def random_word(self, length=6, chars=string.ascii_lowercase):
   return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))

def random_id(self, size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def random_number(self, length=3):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(length))
```

and similar.

See also:

- [Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python)
- [Random strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030053/random-strings-in-python)
- [What's the best way to generate random strings of a specific length in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319101/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-random-strings-of-a-specific-length-in-python)