# python - random string generator _help_

Tags: python, function, random, printing

this is a stupid question ... honestly i don't really have a clue at the moment and am pretty novice to python...

I'm currently wrecking my head on a python script to generate a random password. I found a good start from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319101/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-random-strings-of-a-specific-length-in-python) example by 'Omid Raha'

*edit:* **on revist, this example is far to complex for something that appears to have much simpler ways of performing the same task...**

```
import random
import hashlib
import time

"""
This script is adapted from an example found here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319101/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-random-strings-of-a-specific-length-in-python ; originally provided by user 'Omid Raha'
"""
SECRET_KEY = 'ffdsat9asdf5o5u9HKHvurtiasdf1tg1V36jyasdfSv8Ppin9O'

    try:
    random = random.SystemRandom()
    using_sysrandom = True
except NotImplementedError:
    import warnings
    warnings.warn('A secure pseudo-random number generator is not available '
                  'on your system. Falling back to Mersenne Twister.')
using_sysrandom = False


def get_random_string(length=12,
                      allowed_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
                                '%*/-_@'):
    """
    Returns a securely generated random string.

    The default length of 12 with the a-z, A-Z, 0-9 character set returns
    a 71-bit value. log_2((26+26+10)^12) =~ 71 bits
    """
    if not using_sysrandom:
        # This is ugly, and a hack, but it makes things better than
        # the alternative of predictability. This re-seeds the PRNG
        # using a value that is hard for an attacker to predict, every
        # time a random string is required. This may change the
        # properties of the chosen random sequence slightly, but this
        # is better than absolute predictability.
        random.seed(
            hashlib.sha256(
                ("%s%s%s" % (
                    random.getstate(),
                    time.time(),
                    SECRET_KEY)).encode('utf-8')
            ).digest())
    return ''.join(random.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length))
print (get_random_string)
```

simply returns:

`<function get_random_string at 0x1034f7848>`

I have no clue what this means... or if I'm even properly executing the script.

*edit:*

**thank you, *for reading***

Comment: Put plainly, you are printing the definition of the function, when you want to call the function and print the value. Try `print (get_random_string())` - the parentheses after the function name signal that you want to actually RUN the function, and get the value it has produced.

Comment: @monkey thank you :)  this is very helpful for future endeavors

Answer (score 0):

stumbling along... found this:

```
from OpenSSL import rand

p = rand.seed("lolNOmoreBADpasswds12")
print(p)
```

that:

```
import os, random, string
length = 12
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

print ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length))
```

and the other:

```
from OpenSSL import rand

p = rand.bytes("12")
print(p)
```

playing with things like this, that, and the other now...  `:)`
*edit:* **all the above methods suck**

given: [xkcd rocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uKuY.png)

lets consider this as a best path forward *(for random password generator thats memorable)* **given you have a file containing all the word strings you'd like to include**:

```
import random, string, os
word_file = "./wordlist"
words = open(word_file).read().splitlines()
part1 = random.choice(words)
part2 = random.choice(words)
part3 = random.choice(words)
part4 = random.choice(words)

phrase = part1.capitalize()+part2+part3.capitalize()+part4
print phrase
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest random string Generator i know:

```
import random, string;
all_chars = string.ascii_lowercase
def randstr(length):
    result = str()
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(all_chars)
    return(result)
print(randstr(15))
```

if you want to change the amount of possible characters just change the all_chars variable:

For example:

If you want digits and characters:

```
all_chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
```

For digits and uppercase and lowercase characters:

```
all_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)