# PYTHON : How do I make my program produce a file with a random file name

Tags: python, file, random

```
import time

a = 0
amount = 1
while a < 100:
    userfile = 'random{}'.format(amount)
    file = open(userfile, 'a')
    amount += 1
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(userfile)
    a += 1
```

I've made a program that creates files with a fixed file name. I'm trying to make it so the file name is a randomly generated set of letters but I don't know quite how to apply the random function to it.

Comment: You may be looking for something like the [tempfile library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

Comment: `random.choice(string.ascii_letters)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18319101/whats-the-best-way-to-generate-random-strings-of-a-specific-length-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module provides just what you want:

```
import tempfile

random_filename = tempfile.mktemp(dir="")
```

Sample output: `tmp4STAXd`

The method supports some helpful arguments that you can checkout in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
import string
import random

N = 10
print ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(N)) #=> izWIzBXltM or AZlkWOoTGY or ...
```

Use

```
print ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(N))
```

If you need lowercase only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.ascii_letters` to get list of letters and `random.choice()` to select random letter from list. If you use `for` and `range()` then you can get many random letters and later `join()` them into string.

```
import string
import random

letters = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for x in range(10)]

filename = ''.join(letters)

print(filename)
```

Docs: [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

You have also `string.ascii_lowercase`, `string.digits`, etc. so you can use ie.

```
string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
```