# How to generate random byte string of length n in Python

Tags: python

I want to generate a random byte string of length n in Python. For example, I want byte strings such as `b"helloworld"` generated. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18319156/6828329) answer gives the following code for generating random strings:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

print(''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12)))
```

However, this just generates *strings* and not *byte strings*.

How do I do this?

Comment: `random.randbytes`? `secrets.token_bytes`? `os.urandom`?

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: `bytes(choices(ascii_uppercase.encode(), k=12))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain `encode()` method after your `join()` method:-

```
print(''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12)).encode())
```

**Note:-**
if you want to encode in some specific encoding then pass that encoding as parameter in `encode()` method

Answer (score 2):

simply encode() it.

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase

test = ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(12))
print(test.encode("utf-8"))
```