# python Generate an alphanumeric Sequence

Tags: python

I need a custom alphanumeric sequence for a `custom_id` on django model for each `Product`.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.custom_id is None:
        self.custom_id = f"{custom_seq(self.id)}"
    return super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want custom Alphanumeric sequence to be generated as:

```
eg. letters=4, digits=3 then,
'AAAA001', 'AAAA002', 'AAAA003'... 'ZZZZ999'
if letters =3 and digits =4
'AAA0001', 'AAA0002'... 'ZZZ9999'
```

Here is my try:

```
def custom_seq(pk, letter=4, digits=3):
  init = ''
  alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
  for i in alpha:
    for j in alpha:
      for k in alpha:
         for l in alpha: 
            yield(i+j+k+l)
```

This will genrate only 'AAAA'  to 'ZZZZ', but not sure how to add digits in front of it and make this dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean by "make this dynamic"?  And the `itertools` has a function, `product`, which might be of help.

Comment: @ScottHunter - Thanks, let me check `product`, Dynamic means- in my code you might have observed I have written 4 for looks when letters are 4. Those 4 loops should dynamic, so that if I change the `letters` to some  other `number` say 3 or 5 for loops should change for that number of times.

Comment: what do you want the `self.id` to do when you passed it to `custom_seq` ? Seems like you want a custom generator to yield `AAA001` ... , but how do you want to control where does the sequence start from? Like do you want to control whether first sequence is `AAA001` or `AAA999`?

Comment: @fusion - please ignore, I was planning to initialize with id `itself` instead of digits but the problem was it could have any number of digits such as  2 digits 3 digits etc. which would vary my sequence length

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030081/1294308

Comment: @rriehle - Thanks but Random string would not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use itertools.product in order to get the combinations of alphabets and digits easily.

```
import string
import itertools

def custom_seq(pk, letter=4, digits=3):
    alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
    digit = string.digits
    alpha_list = [alpha]*letter
    digit_list = [digit]*digits
    for i in itertools.product(*alpha_list):
        for j in itertools.product(*digit_list):
            yield "".join(i + j)
            # print("".join(i + j))
```