# Key Error: 'Secret_Key' cant run server in django

Tags: python, django

Hello i just downloaded an open source Django CRM. Im using VSCode.
Installed all the requirements in the dir and inside the venv.
When I try to run the server there is a KeyError.
These are the final lines that the error comes with:
File "C:\Users....\Django-CRM-master\crm\settings.py", line 12, in 
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"]
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 679, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

From what I can see the Secret_key is in the env file.
In settings.py the key is called with SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY"].
I dont seem to see the problem and I read a ton of fixes today that dont fix it :).
Please help.

Comment: It's expecting an environment variable named `SECRET_KEY` to exist, and evidently it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the environment variable doesn't exist on your system by saying that the key `"SECRET_KEY"` is not in the `os.environ` dictionary-like object which represents all your environment variables.

You'll need to generate a long enough random string, then either set a `SECRET_KEY` environment variable on your system, or simply replace the use of `os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` by this string (not recommended but if you're not using this for testing purposes on your own machine that's fine...)

A fun thread on random string generation: [How to generate random strings in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030053/how-to-generate-random-strings-in-python)

I'm not sure what "env file" you're referring to but you seem to be on Windows so:
How to set up environment variables on Windows: [Setting Windows PowerShell environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)

Another thing that might help:

> I can see the Secret_key is in the env file

Environment variables are case-sensitive (`"Secret_key" != "SECRET_KEY"`), so make that sure the key you want to access with `os.environ[<key>]` and the one in your system are the same.

Comment: The size or the kind of the string is not the problem. The system doesnt read anything that has os.environ['.....'] attached to it that is connected to the evn file(the file containing all the environment variables. I managed to get the server running with bypassing the call of the file and just inserting the variables in the fields. But there were still issues and I will look for a different crm project.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what environment variables are. They're not variables in a file. They're key/value pairs stored at the operating system level, in your case Windows. `os.environ` stands for OperatingSystem.environment:https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ